# How to set default rule width/color for tabularray?

Tags: tabularray

Is it possible to specify default values for rule width and rule height that **tabularray** will use (for all tables in the document)?

Using a regular `tabular` environment I can set the default width and color for all tables in the document by using `\arrayrulecolor` and `\arrayrulewidth`. However, the `tblr` environment appears not to use these definitions. The only way I currently see is to repeat the width/color spec for each h/vline definition for each table.

I could use `\SetTblrInner` as commented out in the example, but that only works on tables that have complete h/vlines. This is not always the case, see example. I also don't think a `\NewTableCommand` could help here.

I want to use the new interface, because I wish to separate the table contents from the layout commands. The contents are typically produced by an external program. This is the whole reason for switching to tabularray.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl,tabularray}

\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \cline{2-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&Test&table\\\hline
        tabular&vs&tabularray\\\hline
    \end{tabular}

    %\SetTblrInner{vlines={fg=blue,wd=1pt}, hlines={fg=blue,wd=1pt}}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={ccc},
            vline{1}={2-Z}{fg=blue,wd=1pt}, vline{2-Z}={fg=blue,wd=1pt},
            hline{1}={2-Z}{fg=blue,wd=1pt}, hline{2-Z}={fg=blue,wd=1pt},
            hspan=minimal,
        }
        &Test&table\\
        tabular&vs&tabularray\\
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a paragraph "Default specifications" page 31 of Tabularray's manual. Does it cover your question?

Comment: Not that I can see. From that section I got `\SetTblrInner` and `\NewTableCommand`. The former can be used to set cell color, but I don't see how I can use it for rule colors. The latter be used to redefine custom rules, not exactly what I want, which moreover only seem to work with the old interface. I thought I was going for something really trivial, that I have somehow overlooked.

Comment: `\ExplSyntaxOn \keys_set:nn{tblr-hline}{fg=blue,wd=1pt}\keys_set:nn{tblr-vline}{fg=blue,wd=1pt}\ExplSyntaxOff` should work, but I don't see a real interface for it.